# Connect to two wireless networks at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have two networks in my area one is on a 100Mbps optic connection second one is 10Mbps DSL. I have access to both however the 100Mbps WiFi network is strictly only for uTorrent I can't use it for browsing, can't use putty/ssh or anything else I need for work for all that I have to use 10Mbps now when I'm working I would like to download things in the background is it possible to connect to two networks have uTorrent use the 100Mbps network and the 10Mbps for everything else ?

The person who setup the networks is not around for another 2 months. I have a spare WiFi USB Stick but no idea how to set this up.

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: Please update your question with the following info so we can help: What OS?  What version?

Comment: Added OS version. Windows 8.1 on S430 Lenovo notebook 1 Built-in WiFi adapter and one Atheros USB WiFi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, use a combination of [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) and [route](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) to send traphic for specific ports to one interface and other traphic to the other interface.

See specifically the second example in [this article](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html) for a more elaborate explanation.  In this example, there are two interfaces, "ASTRAL" and "RDS". The following lines are added to the mangle table of iptables:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth0 -p tcp --dprot 80 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

And these to the routing tables (/etc/iproute2/rt_tables):

```
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth1 table RDS
ip route add default via 10.8.8.1 dev eth2 table ASTRAL # the same like in the first example
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table RDS
ip rule add from all fwmark 2 table ASTRAL
```

A similar solution may be working in Windows using [netsh advfirewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(WS.10%29.aspx) instead of iptables and the [route](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490991.aspx) command. However, [this forum discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1fb3189c-3129-4360-8fe5-55b86f4034c9/route-specific-traffic-through-different-nic) suggests that this is not possible. My knowledge of MS Windows isn't good enough to provide a complete solution though. Check [this Server Vault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/92575/how-to-route-different-traffic-thru-different-network-interfaces-in-windows), as it seems similar to your question (routing based on ip range, but not on port number).

Comment: Is there an option for Windows ? Maybe option to have 10Mbps on Ethernet cable/port and wifi over 100Mbps.